# Recortar elementos com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com problemas em mover elementos na tela com javascript puro. Preciso "recortar" o elemento de um lugar -> E enviar este elemento para outro local , e fazer isso com todo o html que esse elemento contiver dentro dele

Existe uma forma de recortar o elemento de um local e enviar para outro?
Ja tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
bemVindo.classList.remove('bemVindo'); novoElemento.classList.add('novoElemento')
```

mas dessa forma ele só altera a classe, e preciso que ele seja "movido" para a outra classe.

Comment: "Movido" que vc fala é recortar um elemento do Header e colar no Footer? Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara...

Comment: Sim, recortar o elemento de um local e "colar" em outro

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi a pergunta corretamente, usando `appendChild` você consegue o que precisa.

```js
const f = () => {
document.getElementById('destino').appendChild(document.getElementById('elemento'))
}
```

```css
#origem {
background-color: red;}

#destino {
background-color: yellow;}

#origem,#destino {height: 60px;
width: 60px;}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
<div id="origem">
<div id="elemento"><a href="#">link</a></div>
</div>
<div id="destino"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="mover" onclick="f()" />
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, com poucos ajustes resolvi minha situação..Muito obrigado